# Is there a possible way to use INSERT OR REPLACE without UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY value?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there any possible way to use `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` without `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` in SQLite?

I want to update values in the table where 4 parameters match with the values if not exists, I want to insert a new row. But these 4 parameters ARE NOT `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` (can be duplicated but a combination of four is unique).

I've tried using `WHERE` but this is not allowed with `INSERT`. Also `UPDATE` alone will not add a new row.

```py
cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO FileNameStatus
    (FileName, Delivery, SW, FuncName, 
    LinkModDate, ExtSrcModDate, ExtSrcModifier,
    ExtAttModDate, ExtAttModifier, Error, Warning)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?)
    WHERE FileName = :file AND Delivery = :dvry AND SW = :sw AND FuncName = :func''',
    (eachRow, {"file": eachRow[0], "dvry": eachRow[1], "sw": eachRow[2], "func": eachRow[3]},
    ))
```

Is it possible to do with SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can instead do is,

- Execute a query to check if a tuple exists with the 4 parameters

```
    QUERY = "query to select the 4 fields"
    cursor.execute(QUERY, params)
#if cursor row count is > 0 then you have the fields present in the database and you can update
#if it is == 0, then you know that they don't exist and you can insert
```

Comment: Did not think about this way, thank you for your answer. it's now working!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS` to check if value is already present:

```
INSERT INTO FileNameStatus(FileName, Delivery, SW, FuncName, 
    LinkModDate, ExtSrcModDate, ExtSrcModifier,ExtAttModDate, ExtAttModifier, Error, Warning)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM FileNameStatus
                 WHERE FileName = :file AND Delivery = :dvry 
                   AND SW = :sw AND FuncName = :func)
```

Comment: like your way, it's simpler than adding extra if/else statement but I got syntax error that I could not fix it :( So just decided to add conditions... Nonetheless, thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a query to check if the data already exists like the following:

```py
    for eachRow in data:
        cur.execute('''SELECT FileName, Delivery, SW, FuncName
                    FROM FileNameStatus
                    WHERE FileName = :file AND Delivery = :dvry AND SW = :sw AND FuncName = :func''',
                    {"file": eachRow[0], "dvry": eachRow[1], "sw": eachRow[2], "func": eachRow[3]})

        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row is None: # row not exist
            cur.execute('''INSERT INTO FileNameStatus
                        (FileName, Delivery, SW, FuncName, LinkModDate, ExtSrcModDate, ExtSrcModifier,
                        ExtAttModDate, ExtAttModifier, Error, Warning)
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?)''',
                        eachRow)
        else: # row exist, just update
            cur.execute('''UPDATE FileNameStatus
                            SET FileName = :file, Delivery = :drvy, SW = :sw, FuncName = :func,
                            LinkModDate = :ld, ExtSrcModDate = :sd, ExtSrcModifier = :sm,
                            ExtAttModDate = :ad, ExtAttModifier = :am, Error = :err, Warning = :warn
                            WHERE FileName = :file AND Delivery = :drvy AND SW = :sw AND FuncName = :func;''',
                        {"file": eachRow[0], "drvy": eachRow[1], "sw": eachRow[2], "func": eachRow[3],
                         "ld": eachRow[4], "sd": eachRow[5], "sm": eachRow[6],
                         "ad": eachRow[7], "am": eachRow[8], "err": eachRow[9], "warn": eachRow[10]})
    # apply the changes
    conn.commit()
```